# Displaying one column of data from a 2d array into a combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to take one column from a 2D array and displaying it into a combobox. The data from the text file I'm using for the 2D array is here, and I want to display 1001, 1010, 1003, and 1005 as the options in the combobox, then depending on which they choose it would display the rest of the data in a listbox:

```
1001,55000,46326.26,7,30,352.61
1010,30000,11757.26,5,15,228.61
1003,1000,406.35,5,1,82.49
1005,5000,2042.72,3,2,207.09
```

So far I've declared the array and loaded the data from the text file:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
string[,] loans = new string[4, 6];
int recordCount = 0;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentLine;
    string[] fields = new string[6];
    int row = 0;
    StreamReader loanReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\loans.txt");
    while (loanReader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        currentLine = loanReader.ReadLine();
        fields = currentLine.Split(',');
        loans[row, 0] = fields[0];
        loans[row, 1] = fields[1];
        loans[row, 2] = fields[2];
        loans[row, 3] = fields[3];
        loans[row, 4] = fields[4];
        loans[row, 5] = fields[5];
        row = row + 1;
    }
    recordCount = row;
    loanReader.Close();
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

How would I single out just the first column to be displayed in the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop on the first column and add each value to the `combobox`

```
int nbrRows = 4;

for(int i = 0; i < nbrRows; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(loans[i, 0]);
}
```

And then when they select a value in the combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int row = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < nbrColumns; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(myArray[row, i]);
    }

}
```

You can get which index was selected with `SelectedIndex` which tells you which row you have to add. Then you loop in that row depending on the amount of columns you have `nbrColumns` (in your case 6) and you add them to the listbox.

You might also want to add at the beginning of the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

If you don't want the old values too stay.